# Find a Cartesian equation for the curve and identify it $ r^2 = 14$

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I've been doing calculus for too long, and am completely blanking on how to do this question. I know you have to use $ r^2 = x^2 + y^2$ but I'm pretty sure I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already there...$r^2 = 14 \implies x^2+y^2 = 14$. This is a circle centered at the origin and have a radius of $\sqrt{14}$.

Comment: Wow. Thank you. I can't believe I didn't see that.